# Apply different Class for each element in a foreach()

Tags: theme-development, php, categories

sorry for the silly question, but I am really lost.
I want to apply the following CSS to the even elements of my foreach.

**CSS**

```
.blogArticles a {
    float: left;
    max-width: 250px;
    width: 25%;
    color: #333;
}

.blogArticles a:nth-child(even) {
    margin: 30px 0 -30px 0;
}
```

**PHP** **UPDATED (I used snap.svg to render the SVG)**

```
<section id="blogArticles" class="blogArticles clearfix">

    <?php

        $page = (isset($_GET['paged'])) ? $_GET['paged'] : 1;

        $args = array(
                    'paged'          => $paged,
                    'orderby' => 'id',
                    'order' => 'DESC',
                    'cat' => 50,
                    'posts_per_page'    => 20,
                    'post_status'      => 'publish',
                    'suppress_filters' => true
                    );                      

        $blogPosts = query_posts( $args );

        if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

        $categories = get_the_category();

        $count = 0;
        if ($categories) {
            foreach($categories as $category) {
                $class = ($count%2 == 0) ? "even" : "";
    ?>

                <a href="#" class="mix <?php echo $category->name; ?> <?php echo $class; ?>" target="_self" onclick="return false;" data-path-hover="m 0,0 0,100 c 24.580441,3.12569 55.897012,-8.199417 90,-8.199417 34.10299,0 65.41956,11.325107 90,8.199417 L 180,0 z">
                    <figure>
                        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : // Check if Thumbnail exists ?>      
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); // Fullsize image for the single post ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <svg viewBox="0 0 180 320" preserveAspectRatio="none"><path d="m 0,0 0,171.14385 c 24.580441,15.47138 55.897012,24.75772 90,24.75772 34.10299,0 65.41956,-9.28634 90,-24.75772 L 180,0 0,0 z"/></svg>
                        <figcaption>
                            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                            <p class="label <?php echo $category->name; ?>"><?php echo $category->name; ?></p>
                            <button>View</button>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </a>

        <?php 
                $count++;
            } 
        } 
        ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

</section>

<div id="pagination">
    <?php html5wp_pagination(); ?>
</div>
```

**function.php**

```
function html5wp_pagination()
{
    global $wp_query;
    $big = 999999999;
    echo paginate_links(array(
        'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link($big)),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
    ));
}
```

The problem is that in the foreach every printed `$class` is even! Any hint on where it is my mistake?
Thank you in advance!

---

***If you have problem, as me, displaying the suggested great pagination function, here is the code fixed for the pagination of @Pieter Goosen***

```
<?php $count = 1; ?>
    <?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $args = array('paged' => $paged,........);
        $blogPosts = new WP_Query( $args );

        if ( $blogPosts->have_posts() ) : ....... while ( $blogPosts->have_posts() ) : $blogPosts->the_post();
            ........
            ........
            ........
        } 
?>
    <?php $count = $count+1; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<div class="clear"></div>

<?php custom_pagination($blogPosts->max_num_pages); ?>
```

Comment: Are there code missing in your php, as your code just don't work at all

Comment: Let me check, sorry!

Comment: Updated the PHP, now it works. But every elements in the `foreach()` is even!

Comment: Mark, just one thing. `wp_reset_query()` is used for `query_posts`. For `WP_Query` you should use `wp_reset_postdata()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should never use [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) to construct custom queries. This is not just my emphasis, but the codex as well. The one big problem with `query_posts` is, it many circumstances, pagination fails

> **Note:** This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes. As explained later, there are better, more performant options to alter the main query. query_posts() is overly simplistic and problematic way to modify main query of a page by replacing it with new instance of the query. It is inefficient (re-runs SQL queries) and will outright fail in some circumstances (especially often when dealing with posts pagination).

Just a point of note, your [`next_posts_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link) `$max_pages` parameter should be set for custom queries, otherwise it will fail

You should always construct custom queries with [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). So your custom query should look like this

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$args = array(
    'paged'          => $paged,
    'orderby' => 'ID',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'cat' => 50,
    'posts_per_page'    => 20,
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true
);                      

$blogPosts = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $blogPosts->have_posts() ) : while ( $blogPosts->have_posts() ) : $blogPosts->the_post();

<----YOUR LOOP---->

endwhile;

// next_posts_link() usage with max_num_pages
next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $blogPosts->max_num_pages );
previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' );

wp_reset_postdata();

endif;
```

Lastly, your counter should start outside the loop, not inside

```
if ( $blogPosts->have_posts() ) : 
    $count = 0;
    while ( $blogPosts->have_posts() ) : $blogPosts->the_post();
```

**EDIT**

Custom pagination function. I don't know who the original author of this function is, but thanks to you if you ever find this answer :-)

```
function custom_pagination($pages = '', $range = 2) {   
   $showitems = ($range * 2)+1;  

  global $paged;
  if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;

      if($pages == '')
      {
         global $wp_query;
         $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
            if(!$pages)
            {
            $pages = 1;
            }
        }   

       if(1 != $pages)
      {
        $string = _x( 'Page %1$s of %2$s' , '%1$s = current page, %2$s = all pages' , 'pietergoosen' );
        echo "<div class='pagination'><span>" . sprintf( $string, $paged, $pages ) . "</span>";
          if($paged > 2 && $paged > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link(1)."'>" . __( '&laquo; First', 'pietergoosen' ) . "</a>";
         if($paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged - 1)."'>" . __( '&lsaquo; Previous', 'pietergoosen' ) . "</a>";

            for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++)
            {
               if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems ))
               {
                    echo ($paged == $i)? "<span class=\"current\">".$i."</span>":"<a href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."' class=\"inactive\">".$i."</a>";
               }
           }

           if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='" . get_pagenum_link($paged + 1)."'>" . __( 'Next &rsaquo;', 'pietergoosen' ) . "</a>";
           if ($paged < $pages-1 &&  $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($pages)."'>" . __( 'Last &raquo;', 'pietergoosen' ) . "</a>";
           echo "</div>\n";
     }
    } //
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the problem, I just removed the `$count = 0` before the `foreach()` and:

```
if ($categories) {
   foreach($categories as $category) {
     if(!isset($count))
        $count = 0;
```

Comment: This is wrong, check my answer

Comment: Using your method, pagination fails! I add the pagination (1,2,.... Next) in my first question. Using my wrong answer, everything is working fine! I know and I already used `WP_Query()`, but in this case the pagination fails! I changed all my code based on another answer found on stackoverflow that has the same problem with pagination!

Comment: That is because you your `next_posts_link` is wrong. Check the link I gave for the post link. `query_posts` is totally wrong and should never be used as an alternative

Comment: I know mate :)
By the way for the better answer!

Comment: I will add an alternative pagination to my answer which works great. You can try it out.